# Construct Pandas DataFrame from Dictionary where Keys = SKU, but values are Date and other fields

Tags: python, pandas, loops, facebook-prophet

I am new to Python so please bear with me.

I am trying to convert what I think may be a nested dictionary into a csv that I can export. Below is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os 
from fbprophet import Prophet

# Read in File
df1 = pd.read_csv('File_Path.csv')

#Create Loop to Forecast Multiple SKUs
def get_prediction(df):
    prediction = {}
    df1 = df.rename(columns={'Date': 'ds','qty_ordered': 'y', 'item_no': 'item'})
    list_items = df1.item.unique()

    for item in list_items:
        item_df = df1.loc[df1['item'] == item]
        # set the uncertainty interval to 95% (the Prophet default is 80%)
        my_model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality= True, seasonality_prior_scale=1.0)
        my_model.fit(item_df)
        future_dates = my_model.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq='M')
        forecast = my_model.predict(future_dates)
        prediction[item] = forecast
    return prediction

# Save predictions to dictionary
df2 = get_prediction(df1)

# Convert dictionary
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df3, index='columns)
```

So the last part of the code is where I am struggling. I need to convert the df2 dictionary to a dataframe (df3) so I can export it to a csv. But it looks as if it is a nested dictionary? Not sure if I need to update my function or not.

This is what a snippet of the dictionary looks like
[image]

I need to export it so it will look like this

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post code/text and no pictures.

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? Is it not clear to me how is this related to `fbprophet. it looks to me a `pandas` question only.

Comment: @rpanai I wasn't sure if there was a built-in loop function that I missed in the fbprophet documentation that could solve my issue which is why I tagged it

Answer (score 1):

First we try to make a reproducible example:

## Data & Imports

```py
from fbprophet import Prophet
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.util.testing\
       .makeTimeDataFrame()\
       .reset_index()\
       .rename(columns={"index":"Date"})


df = pd.melt(df,
             id_vars=["Date"],
             var_name="item_no",
             value_vars=df.columns[1:],
             value_name="qty_ordered")
```

## Using your function

Here I just cleaned a bit your code

```py
# This returns a dict
def get_prediction(df):
    prediction = {}
    df = df.rename(columns={'Date': 'ds','qty_ordered': 'y', 'item_no': 'item'})
    list_items = df.item.unique()

    for item in list_items:
        item_df = df.loc[df['item'] == item]
        # set the uncertainty interval to 95% (the Prophet default is 80%)
        model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality= True, seasonality_prior_scale=1.0)
        model.fit(item_df)
        future_dates = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq='M')
        forecast = model.predict(future_dates)
        prediction[item] = forecast

    return prediction

df1 = get_prediction(df)

# From dictionary to df
df2 = []
for k,v in df1.items():
    v.insert(1, "item", [k]*len(v))
    df2.append(v)

df2 = pd.concat(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

## Output prediction df

If you modify you function a little you could have a `dataframe` as output:

```py
def get_prediction_pandas(df):
    prediction = []
    df = df.rename(columns={'Date': 'ds','qty_ordered': 'y', 'item_no': 'item'})
    list_items = df.item.unique()

    for item in list_items:
        item_df = df.loc[df['item'] == item]
        # set the uncertainty interval to 95% (the Prophet default is 80%)
        model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality= True, seasonality_prior_scale=1.0)
        model.fit(item_df)
        future_dates = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq='M')
        forecast = model.predict(future_dates)
        forecast.insert(1, "item_no", [item]*len(forecast))
        prediction.append(forecast)
    prediction = pd.concat(prediction, ignore_index=True)
    return prediction

# this is a dataframe
df1 = get_prediction_pandas(df)
```